# SpringBoot and IBM MQ connection properties not overrided on deploy

Tags: spring-boot, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I've a SpringBoot App with a local configuration to connect and listen a local Queue

```
ibm:
  mq:
    queueManager: LOCAL_QM
    channel: DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
    connName: localhost(1414)
    user: admin
    password: passw0rd
    user-authentication-m-q-c-s-p: false
```

When a I deploy the app with Gitlab CI some properties are overrided (with a war_name.xml file in ../tomcat/current/conf/Catalina/localhost/) like database connection properties and mq connection properties to listen a Developpement or Qualification environment queue.

But when the app start the database connection is OK but not the MQ connection (The app use the local connection properties defined in the application.yml file)

When I check the xml file on the remote server, the properties are override.
And when I use a tool like spring actuator, I have the right properties override with the specific env properties.

But in the logs: /tomcat/current/logs/catalina.out I can read that the app try to connect to the local queue manage : LOCAL_QM not the specific environment queue.

```
2021-05-11 12:19:23.484 ERROR 14483 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination '***' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=16093, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'LOCAL_QM' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1414)'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2538' ('MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE')
```

The properties are in the same xml file, it works for the database "spring.datasource" but not for MQ "ibm.mq"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Environment name="spring.datasource.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://***:5432/**" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="spring.datasource.username" value="****" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="spring.datasource.password" value="****" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="ibm.mq.queueManager" value="***" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="ibm.mq.channel" value="***" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="ibm.mq.connName" value="***" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="ibm.mq.user" value="***" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <Environment name="ibm.mq.password" value="" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Any idea why the properties are not overrided ?

Thanks

Comment: Which guide / documentation are you following?

Comment: Referring to the spring documentation - docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/… - is the order of override precedence.

Answer (score 0):

This started out as a comment, but as I wrote it I suspected that you are missing the relevant `ibm.mq` properties. If you don't provide the following properties:

```
ibm.mq.queueManager
ibm.mq.channel
ibm.mq.connName
ibm.mq.user
ibm.mq.password
```

then they default to

```
ibm.mq.queueManager=QM1
ibm.mq.channel=DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN
ibm.mq.connName=localhost(1414)
ibm.mq.user=admin
ibm.mq.password=passw0rd
```

ie. localhost.

The `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter` makes use of

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ibm.mq")
```

to read the connection properties. In this module https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring/blob/master/mq-jms-spring-boot-starter/src/main/java/com/ibm/mq/spring/boot/MQConfigurationProperties.java

So it relies on spring to make the properties prefixed with `ibm.mq` available to it. ie. As long as spring through `@ConfigurationProperties` knows how to handle the overrides it will make them available to `mq-jms-spring-boot-starter`.